# Datagridview Sum For ListItems

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I am looking for a sql query that can sum up some list items from datagrid view.

ListItems= {a, b, c, d}

I have a 'ItemsName' and 'ItemsValues' columns in my datagrid view where i want to sum up some values for 'ItemsName' from datagrid view. I am aware about iteration method which can be run for each list item then for each datagrid view row but i don't want to use that as it may take little time in case there is heavy data in database.

I'm looking something like:

Select Sum(ItemValue)
From ItemTable
Where ItemName= ListItems

Here Listitems is variable which store some list values for which I require sum as shown above.

Please guide.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do something like `SELECT Sum(ItemValue) FROM ItemTable GROUP BY ItemName`. ???

Comment: You should also include ItemName in the fields to select so that it shows the total per grouping

Comment: Hey Charles, I want to show sum value  for the list items and that sum value will be shown somewhere on label in form. I dont want groupby sum.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a datatable as source you could use something like this

```
Dim dt As DataTable = myDataSet.Tables("mytable")
Dim sum As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM(columnname)", "Columname = a OR Columname = b OR Columname = c OR Columname = c))
```

Comment: I want sum for specific items that are stored in list (like: a, b c, d... etc.). Please guide? Im using datagrid view that is bound to table adapter

Comment: I really don't believe there is a good solution, besides create a new tableadadter and use a select statement like Charles AMy suggested. Of Course for tables exists a Dim dr as Datarows() = dt.Select("Columname = a OR Columname = b OR Columname = c OR Columname = c")

Comment: The example you have given consist only 4 columns a to d. But what if my list items vary each time? List Item can contain any lenght as it is created dynamically. Can you please help creating a table adapter for N no. Of items and then sum up these items from another table?

Comment: Then you have to do ot 4 computes nut you use dt.Compute("SUM(columnname)", "Columname = a OR Columname = b OR Columname = c OR Columname = c")or you program a dataadapter/tableadapter with a Select sum(column1), sum(coumn2), sum (column3) FROM ItemTable Where Columname = a OR Columname = b OR Columname = c OR Columname = c

Comment: This solution seems static. Just to clarify more, I have created a list on run time that store some list items (not sure how many items will be stored in this list). I have a table with 2 columns 'ItemName' and 'ItemPrice'. Now if i want to make a sum for some items that are stored in list, how this can be done?

Comment: You build the where clause(that's the part with Columname = a and so on) itemName = CStr(MyListBox.Items(index)) for every listitem and combine them with or.

Comment: That was i was talking about. This is the last optiin which can be used. Though i was aware about this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use datarelations to achieve this goal.

```
    Dim SourceDT As New DataTable With {.TableName = "Source"}
    Dim ChildDT As New DataTable
    ChildDT = SourceDT.Copy
    ChildDT.TableName = "Child"
    Dim Dset As New DataSet
    Dset.Tables.Add(SourceDT)
    Dset.Tables.Add(ChildDT)
    Dset.Relations.Add("SourceToChild",
                       Dset.Tables("Source").Columns("ItemsName"),
                       Dset.Tables("Child").Columns("ItemsName"), False)
    Dset.Tables("Source").Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {
                                      .ColumnName = "SUMofValues",
                                      .DataType = GetType(Double),
                                      .Expression = "SUM(Child(SourceToChild).ItemsValue)"})
```